# How can I merge two or more arrays containing several objects into one and increment their IDs?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have three arrays of objects like so

```
  const arr1 = [{id: 1, name: 'Jay'}, {id: 2, name: 'Kay'}];
    const arr2 = [{id: 1, name: 'Pete'}, {id: 2, name: 'Liam'}];
    const arr3 = [{id: 1, name: 'Baby'}, {id: 2, name: 'Neeson'},  {id: 3, name: 'Kobe'}];
```

and I want to merge them into a single array like this

```
const bigArray = [{id: 1, name: 'Jay'}, {id: 2, name: 'Kay'},{id: 3, name: 'Pete'}, {id: 4, name: 'Liam'}, {id: 5, name: 'Baby'}, {id: 6, name: 'Neeson'},  {id: 7, name: 'Kobe'}];
```

I know I can spread them into a single array using the spread operator but I also need the IDs incremented when they are joined. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reassign the id based on the index:

```
 const merged = [...arr1, ...arr2, ...arr3];
 merged.forEach((el, index) => el.id = index + 1);
```

Comment: your solution looks the simplest. Thankyou

Comment: @camelCase Accept his answer so that others know that the solution worked for you

Answer (score 1):

Add all the array in a single array and than map over it and change index according to need.

```js
const arr1 = [{id: 1, name: 'Jay'}, {id: 2, name: 'Kay'}];
const arr2 = [{id: 1, name: 'Pete'}, {id: 2, name: 'Liam'}];
const arr3 = [{id: 1, name: 'Baby'}, {id: 2, name: 'Neeson'},  {id: 3, name: 'Kobe'}];
    
let arr = [...arr1,...arr2,...arr3]

let op = arr.map((ele, index) => ({...ele, id: index+1}) )

console.log(op)
```

Comment: nice and elegant. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the arrays to a single array using [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) and [`Array.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat), and then you can use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to update the objects with the `id` generated from the index:

```js
const flatAndInc = (...args) =>
  args.flat()
  .map((o, idx) => ({
    ...o,
    id: idx + 1
  }));

const arr1 = [{id: 1, name: 'Jay'}, {id: 2, name: 'Kay'}];
const arr2 = [{id: 1, name: 'Pete'}, {id: 2, name: 'Liam'}];
const arr3 = [{id: 1, name: 'Baby'}, {id: 2, name: 'Neeson'},  {id: 3, name: 'Kobe'}];

const result = flatAndInc(arr1, arr2, arr3);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could map new objects without mutating the given data.

```js
const
    arr1 = [{id: 1, name: 'Jay'}, {id: 2, name: 'Kay'}],
    arr2 = [{id: 1, name: 'Pete'}, {id: 2, name: 'Liam'}],
    arr3 = [{id: 1, name: 'Baby'}, {id: 2, name: 'Neeson'},  {id: 3, name: 'Kobe'}],
    result = [arr1, arr2, arr3].reduce(
        (id => (r, a) => (a.forEach(({ name }) => r.push({ id: id++, name })), r))(1),
        []
    );

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

All of the other answers are valid, and are mostly more efficient and easier than mine. However, my answer is one of the easiest to understand.

My code uses [Spread Syntax (`...`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to create the big array, but all that does is combines the arrays. Then, I use a [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop to loop through the array, and redefine the id. Then I incremented the `id` variable, so that the id's were in order.

```js
const arr1 = [{id: 1, name: 'Jay'}, {id: 2, name: 'Kay'}];
const arr2 = [{id: 1, name: 'Pete'}, {id: 2, name: 'Liam'}];
const arr3 = [{id: 1, name: 'Baby'}, {id: 2, name: 'Neeson'},  {id: 3, name: 'Kobe'}];
let id = 1;
const bigArray = [...arr1, ...arr2, ...arr3];

bigArray.forEach(e => {
  e.id = id;
  id++;
});

console.log(bigArray);
```

Comment: @camelCase thanks. I tried to make my code as simple as possible so that others can understand. However, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55080421/10768127) is the best

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```
 const arr1 = [{id: 1, name: 'Jay'}, {id: 2, name: 'Kay'}];
 const arr2 = [{id: 1, name: 'Pete'}, {id: 2, name: 'Liam'}];
 const arr3 = [{id: 1, name: 'Baby'}, {id: 2, name: 'Neeson'},  {id: 3, name: 'Kobe'}];

 var result = Array.from([...arr1, ...arr2, ...arr3], ({name}, i)=>{ return {id: i + 1, name} });
 console.log(result);
```

Comment: why does the id of each object in the resulting array start from 0?

Comment: i have set id by array index, thats whys it start from 0, but now i have updated it. Now it start from 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Map) and [**Spread Syntax**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

1. Pass an `array` of all the arrays you want to merge to function
2. Flat that `array` using spread operator.
3. Then use `reduce()` to convert all the arrays to single dimensional array.
4. At last use `map()` and set it `id` property to `index + 1`

```js
const arr1 = [{id: 1, name: 'Jay'}, {id: 2, name: 'Kay'}];
    const arr2 = [{id: 1, name: 'Pete'}, {id: 2, name: 'Liam'}];
    const arr3 = [{id: 1, name: 'Baby'}, {id: 2, name: 'Neeson'},  {id: 3, name: 'Kobe'}];
    
    
function merge(arrays){
  return [...arrays].reduce((ac,a) => [...ac,...a],[]).map((x,i) => ({...x,id:i+1}));
}
console.log(merge([arr1,arr2,arr3]));
```

Comment: pls look at this solution again

Comment: you fixed it, nice one